# Manipulando botões nos itens de uma lista

Tags: android, listview

Pessoal estou com um problema em minha lista.

Em minha lista é igual a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As setas deveriam amentar o numero de gols do textView correspondente, mas não é isso que ocorre. Independente do item em que cliquei nas seta o valor aumentado é sempre o do ultimo item. Por exemplo se clico na seta para aumentar a quantidade de gols do Palmeiras, eu acabo aumentando o do Paraná.

Creio que o problema seja que não estou conseguindo retomar o item da lista em que o botão foi clicado e por isso o problema só pode ser no meu adapter.

Segue:

```
public class AdaptadorLista extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Jogo> itens;
    private View viewSelecionada;
    private int golsMandante=0;
    private int golsVisitante=0;
    private int gols=0;
    private boolean btMaisPressionado = false;
    private boolean btMenosPressionado = false;
    private ItemSuporte itemSuporte;
    private int posicaoNaLista;

    public AdaptadorLista(Context context, List<Jogo> itens) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.itens = itens;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itens.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itens.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(view == null){
            itemSuporte = new ItemSuporte();
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista, null);
            itemSuporte.btMaisGolsMandante=((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btMaisGolsMandante));

            itemSuporte.btMaisGolsVisitante=((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btMaisGolsVisitante));

            itemSuporte.btMenosGolsMandante=((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btMenosGolsMandante));

            itemSuporte.btMenosGolsVisitante=((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btMenosGolsVisitante));

            itemSuporte.txtPlacarMandante=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPlacarMandante));
            itemSuporte.txtPlacarVisitante=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPlacarVistante));
            itemSuporte.txtNomeMandante=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSimboloMandante));
            itemSuporte.txtNomeVisitante=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSimboloVisitante));
            itemSuporte.txtDataJogo=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDataJogo));
            itemSuporte.txtLocalJogo=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtLocalJogo));
            itemSuporte.simboloMandante=((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgMandante));
            itemSuporte.simboloVisitante=((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgVisitante));
            view.setTag(itemSuporte);

        } else {
            itemSuporte= (ItemSuporte)view.getTag();
        }

        Jogo jogo = itens.get(position);
        itemSuporte.simboloMandante.setImageResource(jogo.getTimeMandante().getCodigoImagemSimbolo());
        itemSuporte.simboloVisitante.setImageResource(jogo.getTimeVisitante().getCodigoImagemSimbolo());
        itemSuporte.txtNomeMandante.setText(jogo.getTimeMandante().getSigla());
        itemSuporte.txtNomeVisitante.setText(jogo.getTimeVisitante().getSigla());
        itemSuporte.txtPlacarMandante.setText(Integer.toString(jogo.getGolsMandante()));
        itemSuporte.txtPlacarVisitante.setText(Integer.toString(jogo.getGolsVisitante()));
        itemSuporte.txtDataJogo.setText(jogo.getData());
        itemSuporte.txtLocalJogo.setText(jogo.getLocal());

        itemSuporte.btMaisGolsMandante.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                viewSelecionada = v;

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    btMaisPressionado=true;
                    new AumentaGols().execute();
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    btMaisPressionado = false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });


        itemSuporte.btMenosGolsMandante.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                viewSelecionada = v;

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    btMenosPressionado = true;
                    new DiminuiGols().execute();
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    btMenosPressionado = false;
                }
                return true;
            }

        });


        itemSuporte.btMaisGolsVisitante.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                viewSelecionada = v;

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    btMaisPressionado = true;
                    new AumentaGols().execute();
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    btMaisPressionado = false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        itemSuporte.btMenosGolsVisitante.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                viewSelecionada = v;

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    btMenosPressionado=true;
                    new DiminuiGols().execute();
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                    btMenosPressionado = false;

                }
                return true;
            }

        });

        return view;
    }

    public void setGols(){
        switch (viewSelecionada.getId()) {
            case R.id.btMaisGolsMandante:
            gols = golsMandante;            
            break;

            case R.id.btMenosGolsMandante:
            gols = golsMandante;
            break;

            default:
            gols = golsVisitante;
            break;
        }
    }

    private class ItemSuporte {
        ImageView simboloMandante;
        ImageView simboloVisitante;
        TextView txtPlacarMandante;
        TextView txtPlacarVisitante;
        TextView txtNomeMandante;
        TextView txtNomeVisitante;
        TextView txtDataJogo;
        TextView txtLocalJogo;
        ImageButton btMaisGolsMandante;
        ImageButton btMaisGolsVisitante;
        ImageButton btMenosGolsMandante;
        ImageButton btMenosGolsVisitante;

    }

    class AumentaGols extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            while (btMaisPressionado) {
                setGols();
                if(gols<9){
                    gols++;
                    publishProgress(gols);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            if(viewSelecionada.getId()== R.id.btMaisGolsMandante){
                itemSuporte.txtPlacarMandante.setText(String.valueOf(gols));
                golsMandante=gols;
            }
            if(viewSelecionada.getId()== R.id.btMaisGolsVisitante){
                itemSuporte.txtPlacarVisitante.setText(String.valueOf(gols));
                golsVisitante=gols;
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(viewSelecionada.getId() == R.id.btMaisGolsMandante){
                itemSuporte.txtPlacarMandante.setText(String.valueOf(gols));
                golsMandante=gols;
            }
            if(viewSelecionada.getId() == R.id.btMaisGolsVisitante){
                itemSuporte.txtPlacarVisitante.setText(String.valueOf(gols));
                golsVisitante=gols;
            }
        }

    }

    class DiminuiGols extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (btMenosPressionado) {
                if(gols>0){
                    gols--;
                    publishProgress(gols);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            if(viewSelecionada.getId() == R.id.btMenosGolsMandante){
                itemSuporte.txtPlacarMandante.setText(String.valueOf(gols));
                golsMandante=gols;
            }
            if(viewSelecionada.getId() == R.id.btMenosGolsVisitante){
                itemSuporte.txtPlacarVisitante.setText(String.valueOf(gols));
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(viewSelecionada.getId() == R.id.btMenosGolsMandante){
                itemSuporte.txtPlacarMandante.setText(String.valueOf(gols));
                golsMandante=gols;
            }
            if(viewSelecionada.getId() == R.id.btMenosGolsVisitante){
                itemSuporte.txtPlacarVisitante.setText(String.valueOf(gols));
                golsVisitante=gols;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Layout de cada item item_lista.xml:

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDataJogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="10/11 - 21:00" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgMandante"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:src="@drawable/parana2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSimboloMandante"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="PAR"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btMaisGolsMandante"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="@drawable/setaparacima" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtPlacarMandante"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="2"
                android:textSize="50sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btMenosGolsMandante"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="@drawable/setaparabaixo" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="x"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btMaisGolsVisitante"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="@drawable/setaparacima" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtPlacarVistante"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="50sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btMenosGolsVisitante"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="@drawable/setaparabaixo" />

        </LinearLayout>

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/txtSimboloVisitante"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:text="AVA"
             android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgVisitante"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:src="@drawable/avai2" />

    </LinearLayout>
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLocalJogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Allianz Parque" />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu ***adapter*** parece-me bem.
O problema está no uso do `itemSuporte`.
Note que o `itemSuporte` é utilizado sempre que uma linha da `listView` necessita de ser desenhada.
No final de toda a lista ser apresentada ela irá apontar para o *layout/view* da última linha.

Você tem de utilizar outra variável para guardar qual o *layout/view* a que pertence o botão pressionado. Ela terá de ser inicializada em cada um dos métodos `onTouch`.

Não sei como é o *layout* da linha da `listView`.
Supondo que todos os elementos estão incluídos em um mesmo *layout*, esse *layout/view* poderá ser obtido no `onTouch` recorrendo ao método `getParent()` da `view` passada.
Depois é só utilizar `findViewById` para obter as outras `views` da linha.

**EDIT** (Após ver xml)

Parece que o botão e o text que você quer alterar estão no mesmo `LinearLayout`.
Assim sendo faça o seguinte:

```
private LinearLayout linhaLista;
```

Em cada `onTouch`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    viewSelecionada = v;
    linhaLista = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
    ...
    ...
}
```

Nos métodos `onProgressUpdate()` e `onPostExecute()` utilize `linhaLista` para obter os `textView`:

```
TextView txtPlacarMandante = (TextView)linhaLista.findViewById(R.id.txtPlacarMandante)
TextView txtPlacarVistante = (TextView)linhaLista.findViewById(R.id.txtPlacarVistante)
```

Comment: Inclui o Layout dos itens. Seria como pegar a view do item que contém o botão e o text que quero alterar?

Comment: @caezar Editei a minha resposta.

Comment: Perfeito @ramaral, pena que ainda não tenho pontos para poder avaliar a sua reposta!